# How i can fix mail() function on PHP?

Tags: php, iis, hmail-server

I use the Internet Information Services(IIS) with PHP. But the mail() function doesn't seem to be working.
At first I tried to fix the php.ini. Then I downloaded hMailServer. Now it shows "Your message has been sent!" but I haven't got any messages in my inbox. I also checked the SPAM inbox. But I can't find anything.

```php
<?php 

    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    set_error_handler("var_dump");
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = "yunishuseynzade1102@gmail.com";
    $message = "Hello how are you?";
    $from = 'dj.yunis.official@gmail.com'; 
    $to = 'yunishuseynzade1102@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Customer Inquiry';
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }


?>
```

Comment: Is this hosted on a shared environment or your local environment?

Comment: check your mail server logs

Comment: Check your spam filter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 4 Parameter($from) is wrong because it expects an string with header information.
you only post a email into it.
cange your $from to:

```
$from = 'From: dj.yunis.official@gmail.com';
```

Comment: I changed it but don't works.Writes "Message Sent!" but i can not find it on my inbox.

Comment: @YunisHuseynzade You cannot send mail to gmail addresses from other Gmail addresses if you use your own mail server. Use a mail address hosted on the IIS

Answer (score 0):

Configure SMTP E-Mail in IIS:

- open iis manager.
- Features View, double-click SMTP E-mail.
- On the SMTP E-mail page, type the e-mail address of the sender in the E-mail address text box.
- On the SMTP E-mail page, select any delivery method.
- Deliver e-mail to SMTP server:
  [image]
- If Store e-mail in pickup directory is selected, type the batch
  e-mail location in the Store e-mail in pickup directory text box.
- Click Apply in the Actions pane.

set below setting in the php.ini file:

```
[mail function]
SMTP=localhost
sendmail_from = string
smtp_port=25
```

Update:

You need to check your junk mail folder.

Below is my working example:

my mail send code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]